# How do I write an HTML entity in button text in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, button, html-encode

I need to write out a submit button in ASP.NET so that the button text value is HTML-encoded using the proper HTML entities for the various French characters with accents.

The button is simply declared as

```
<asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" />
```

If I do something like

```
button1.text = "Test é"
```

then it displays the button text correctly as **Test é** in the web page, but the HTML source is also **Test é**, which is not what I need -- I need either &eacute; or &#233;.

If I do something like

```
button1.text = server.htmlencode("Test é")
```

then it displays **Test &#233;** in the button text, i.e. **Test &amp;#233;** in the HTML source.

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the text without encoding anything. You can try to set globalization setting in web.config inside system.web as follows(Not sure if ISO-8859-1 is the correct encoding for french):

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" culture="fr-FR" enableClientBasedCulture="true"  responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1" fileEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
```