# Unable to set text with special characters in a button at runtime

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing an asp.net page with to webcontrols, a label and a button.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="&eacute;" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
       </div>
   </form>
```

In the page load event, I'm trying to fill the text property with special caracters:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

           string text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("élèves");
           Label1.Text = Button1.Text = text;
   }
```

When I browse the file, I wonder why the label displays "éléves" but the button displays "&#233;l&#232;ves".
In the browser, the source code of the page, button's text starts with "&amp;". It looks like asp.net transform the "&" (from "&#233;") into the html equivalent '&amp;'.

If I set it at design time:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="&eacute;l&egrave;ves" />
```

The caption of the button is "élèves" like expected

What happens ? ... how to add special caracters in the text of a button at runtime ?

I expected to have the right (french) text: "élèves" caption for the button (like the label).

I have been searching on the net for a moment but no result. I have just tested to set the page directive VALIDATEREQUEST to false but no success.

Here is the source code interpreted/received by the browser:

```
    <div>
       <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="&amp;#233;l&amp;#232;ves" id="Button1" />
       <br />
       <span id="Label1">&#233;l&#232;ves</span>
    </div>
```

The result on the screen is:[image]

I have found this: [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694087/how-do-i-write-an-html-entity-in-button-text-in-asp-net) but the solution does not work

Comment: One of your problems is the missing begin <div> to match your ending </div>,

Comment: thank you, the tag is present in the aspx page but I missed it in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button text does not require encoding. This works in my system:

```
Button1.Text = "élèves"
Label1.Text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("élèves")
```

Comment: You are right. I though that if accented letters weren't translated then special caracters weren't translated too.
I was wrong. I have made a test with apostrophe and quotes and special caratcers are well (and automatically; no need of htmlencode) translated if needed (in the rendercontent() method) .... In the future, I'll be more confident about what microsoft has done.
I'm still guessing why accented letters don't need to be translated into html entities but I'll live like that (maybe due to the UTF-8 encoding of the page). ty

Comment: Keep in mind that asp.net generates standard html. Take a look at the asp.net generated html using view source. The label puts the text in an html span.  The button creates a normal html input statement with the text defined in a value parameter.

Answer (score 0):

this line of code makes no sense:

```
Label1.Text = Button1.Text = text;
```

either you want this:

```
string mytext = "abc";
Label1.Text = mytext;
button1.Text = mytext;
```

Or say this:

```
Label1.Text = "abc";
button1.Text = Lable1.Text;
```

or, with encoding, then try this:

```
 Button1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("&eacute;l&egrave;ves");
```

Comment: Using the HtmlDecode is what I want to avoid, having special caracter not translated into the equivalent html code. IT does mean 'é' should be '&eacute;' in the source code of the page. It works well with a label but not with a textbox. I have edited the post (at the end) by adding the source code of the page received/interpretated by the browser. ty